# Spring batch jobParameters value null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In a spring batch, I'm trying to pass `jobParameters` and use them in my `JdbcCursorItemReader`. A snippet from the same is:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

    private String demoVar;

    public String getDemoVar() {
        return demoVar;
    }

    public void setDemoVar(@Value("#{jobParameters['demoVarValue']}") String demoVar) {
        this.demoVar = demoVar;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader1() {
        String sqlQuery = String.format("select * FROM TABLE_NAME where demoVar=? ");
        System.out.println(demoVar);
        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> cursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        cursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        cursorItemReader.setSql(sqlQuery);
        cursorItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {
           public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
              preparedStatement.setString(1, demoVar);
           }
        });
        cursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new DbRowMapper());
        return cursorItemReader;
    }
...
```

Controller class(containing job launcher):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/load")
public class LoadController {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public BatchStatus load() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                    .addString("demoVarValue", "001")
                                    .toJobParameters();
        
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

        System.out.println("JobExecution: " + jobExecution.getStatus());

        return jobExecution.getStatus();
    }
}
```

But in the `reader` bean, the value of the `demoVar` parsed from `jobParameters` is being passed as `null` instead of the expected `001`.

Comment: By the way where are you calling this setter   " public void setDemoVar()"
unless you call it how exactly will the spring inject using @Value() annotation.
you have 3 solutions for it
1. you should have @Autowired on setDemoVar()
2. Or you can move that (@Value )to field declaration 
3. or move it to the bean definition method reader1()

Comment: @Lucia Options 1 and 2 lead to the exception ```EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?``` Option 3 works if I make a change in my step1 definition bean, from ```.reader(reader1())``` to ```.reader(reader1(null))```. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `demoVar` field (unless you are calling the getter somewhere else). You can pass it as a parameter of reader's bean definition method:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader1(@Value("#{jobParameters['demoVarValue']}") String demoVar) {
    String sqlQuery = String.format("select * FROM TABLE_NAME where demoVar=? ");
    System.out.println(demoVar);
    JdbcCursorItemReader<User> cursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    cursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    cursorItemReader.setSql(sqlQuery);
    cursorItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(new PreparedStatementSetter() {
       public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
          preparedStatement.setString(1, demoVar);
       }
    });
    cursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new DbRowMapper());
    return cursorItemReader;
}
```

Late binding of job parameters is explained in the [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: I've tried this, but it gives an error ```The method reader1(String) in the type SpringBatchConfig is not applicable for the arguments ()```, in the ```Step1``` bean where I configure the reader1 and writer1. **Edit**: To make it work, I had to change it to ```.reader(reader1(null))``` in the ```step1``` bean.

Comment: Changed **```.reader(reader1())```** to **```.reader(reader1(null))```** and it worked. Still confused about the significance of passing ```null```

Comment: Of course, since the method signature has changed to accept a new parameter you have to update the call site accordingly. You need to pass `null` because the value of the job parameter is not known at configuration time. It will be injected at runtime when the parameter will be resolved. If the answer helped, please accept it.